# Move documents over sites using Sharepoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint, move, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

The action available in SPD  2013 i.e. (Copy Documents) copies document to a library in the same site, but the requirement is to move it in a library located in a top level site without any custom coding.

Is there a way to do it using web services in Sharepoint 2013 Designer?

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem ? interesting question!

Comment: @michaalis no,not yet.Do you have a similar requirement?